# Function of $this->middleware('auth:guard') and $this->middleware('guest:guard')

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel documentation says that we can pass parameter to a middleware specifying with `:`. [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#middleware-parameters)

So, If I am passing a guard as a parameter to  `guest` or `auth` middleware like :

`$this->middleware('guest:admin')`

OR

`$this->middleware('auth:admin')`

What does that mean?

As here in **AdminController.php**

```
    class AdminController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin')->except(['show_login','login']);
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->only(['show_login','login']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter specifies the guard to authenticate the user with, [see the docs (scroll down to "Specifying A Guard")](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes).

More info about custom guards: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards

The `auth` middleware is defined in [`App\Http\Kernel:54`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L54) and you can change the redirect URL in `\App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` and `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` respectively

Answer (score 0):

you can get that parameter in middleware handle method.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
        // Redirect...
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

for more info read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#middleware-parameters).

Comment: I am talking about guards not role assigned to a user table. Here admin has its own provider and guard.

Comment: I just want to know what is the work of  `$this->middleware('auth:admin')` and `$this->middleware('guest:admin')` here?

Comment: `guest` means, that your user not authenticated, so, `guest:admin` is nonsense.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari you take that parameter in middleware handle method.

Comment: @VaheShak I removed `admin` from `$this->middleware('guest:admin')`. Now I can access the `login` route even If I am logged in.  How can it be nonsense then?

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari no, you can't. Normally, if you logged in, you will be redirected after visit login page.

Comment: @VaheShak Ofcourse it will redirect to a page, say 'home page'. But if you remove  `admin` from it you  can't say to where to redirect user if they are authenticated. So by passing a parameter to the `guest` middleware, we can now check where to redirect based on the guard if it's `admin` or `user` So, `admin` in `guest:admin` has a role, it's not nonsense.